# missing images and old links after migrating Prestashop website

Tags: php, .htaccess, content-management-system, migration, prestashop

I just migrated a prestashop website to a new server everything is working there but there are some navigation links which are going to the old domain and also on the home page images are missing. On the other pages images are showing properly but the image path is from old domain. help me with this as I changed the url in SEO & URL under prefernces. Also cleared cache and changed shop_url in database also. but nothing helped. new link is `http://216.144.246.92/`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is mainly because of not updating the site url in `database`.

Just search the main domain in the sql file(database backup). As of my knowledge we need to replace above 50 places with our new site `domain url`.

We tried this already and after changing the main site url (localhost/presta/any, if working in local) it works fine. Hope this helps.